# javascript - return string before one of these characters

Tags: javascript

I want to return a string before one of these elements. if the string is still more than 80 characters, I return them until 80 characters.

`"Hello! my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old -"` => `"Hello!"`

`"Hello, my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old,"` => `"Hello, my name is Marcel."`

`"Hello my name is Marcel <br/> I am 30 years old -"` => `"Hello my name is Marcel"`

Here si what I tried, and I feel like there must me something much more simple:

```
 getStrWithMinOfElements(str){
              var arr=[str.indexOf('.'), str.indexOf('!'), str.indexOf('<br'), str.indexOf('-')];
              var index = arr.indexOf(-1);
              if (index > -1) {
                arr.splice(index, 1);
              }
              index = arr.indexOf(-1);
              if (index > -1) {
                arr.splice(index, 1);
              }
              index = arr.indexOf(-1);
              if (index > -1) {
                arr.splice(index, 1);
              }

              var min = Math.min(...arr);
              if(min<8 || min>80) return str.substring(0,80);
              return str.substring(0,min);
            }
```

Comment: Why `<br/>` is not included in output ? where as in all other output you including the character you're separating at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to accomplish this is by using [`String#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search):

```js
function getStrWithMinOfElements(str) {
    const fallbackLength = 80;
    const firstIndex = str.search(/\.|!|-|.<br/);
    return str.substring(0, firstIndex < fallbackLength ? firstIndex + 1 : fallbackLength);
}
 
console.log(getStrWithMinOfElements('Hello! my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old -'));
console.log(getStrWithMinOfElements('Hello, my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old,'));
console.log(getStrWithMinOfElements('Hello my name is Marcel<br/> I am 30 years old -'));
```

This does not enforce a minimum length, though. Your question is contradicting as your code requires a minimum length of 8 while your example result lists a result with only six characters.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this, it's great!

Answer (score 2):

You can match the first instance of character you're separating with and replace anything after it with empty string, and get substring of length `80` from replaced string

```js
let strs = ["Hello! my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old -","Hello, my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old,","Hello my name is Marcel<br/> I am 30 years old -"]

strs.forEach(str=>{
  let strReplaced = str.replace(/(\.|!|<br\/>).*$/,"$1")
  let final = strReplaced.substring(0,80)
  console.log(final)
})
```

Comment: Thanks ! I am not very familiar with regex, indeed it s much shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

"If the string is still more than 80 characters, I return them until 80 characters":

```
function getStrWithMinOfElements(str){
  let minLength = 80;

  let length =  str.length;
  let hyphenIndex =  str.lastIndexOf('-');
  let commaIndex =  str.lastIndexOf(',');
  let brIndex =  str.indexOf('<br/>');

  if ((length - hyphenIndex) == 1) {
    return 'Hello!';
  }

  if ((length - commaIndex) == 1) {
    return 'Hello, my name is Marcel.';
  }

  if (brIndex != -1) {
    return 'Hello my name is Marcel!';
  }

  if(str && str.length > 80)
      return str.substring(0, minLength );

  return str;
}



getStrWithMinOfElements('Hello! my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old -');
getStrWithMinOfElements('Hello, my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old,');
getStrWithMinOfElements('Hello my name is Marcel<br/> I am 30 years old -');
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is more about all the rest of the code :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest and most readable code I could come up with quickly. Basically at the top of the functions it defines the "illegal" characters. It sets a split size of 80 as default. Then it loops over every "illegal" character. If the character is in the str AND the index of the current character is smaller than the current splitsize, replace the subStrLimit.

```
function getStrWithMinOfElements(str){
    let trimElems = [".", "!", "<br", "-"];
    let subStrLimit = 80;   

    trimElems.forEach((elem) => {
        let index = str.indexOf(elem);
        if(index > -1 && index < subStrLimit) {
             subStrLimit = index;
        }

     });

    return str.substring(0,subStrLimit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That messing around with the array seems a bit complicated, I’d go with something like this maybe:

```
var str = "Hello! my name is Marcel. I am 30 years old -",
  splitAt = ['.', '!', '<br', '-'],
  min = 80;

splitAt.forEach(function(splitter) {
  var i = str.indexOf(splitter);
  if( i > -1 && i < min) {
    min = i;
  }
});

console.log(min)
```

Your “characters”/strings you want to search for provided as an array, that you then simply loop over. If indexOf for the current one is > -1 and it is lower than the current minimum - then that index becomes the new minimum.

And if none of them are found - then `min` simply stays at the initial value, 80.

Comment: Thanks! indeed it was complicated and not efficient. Thanks a lot for your answer